# How to Remove '\0' from a string in C#?

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to remove '\0' from a string. This may be very simple but it's not for me since I'm a new C# developer.

I've this code:

```
public static void funcTest (string sSubject, string sBody)
{
    Try
      {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage(); // Set up e-mail message.
        msg.To = XMLConfigReader.Email;
        msg.From = XMLConfigReader.From_Email;
        msg.Subject = sSubject;
        msg.body="TestStrg.\r\nTest\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\r\n";     
      }
    catch (Exception ex) 
      {
        string sMessage = ex.Message;     
        log.Error(sMessage, ex);   
      }
}
```

But what I want is:

```
msg.body="TestStrg.\r\nTest\r\n";
```

So, is there a way to do this with a simple code?

Answer (score 64):

It seems you just want the [`string.Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) function (static method).

```
var cleaned = input.Replace("\0", string.Empty);
```

Edit: Here's the complete code, as requested:

```
public static void funcTest (string sSubject, string sBody)
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.To = XMLConfigReader.Email;
        msg.From = XMLConfigReader.From_Email;
        msg.Subject = sSubject;
        msg.Body = sBody.Replace("\0", string.Empty);
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        string sMessage = ex.Message;     
        log.Error(sMessage, ex);   
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Noldorin....

So how I add this code line into my function. Because when I add a new line of code to the function, it is not executed and I don`t know why..

Please help me how to insert this line of code you provide into my  function in order to be executed normally.

Thank you a lot...

Comment: When I alter the line:
 msg.body = sBody.Replace("\0", string.Empty);
a bulid error is generated: 'System.Web.Mail.MailMessage.body' is inaccessible due to its protection level.

1)Why is that?
2)When I add a new code into my project. It doesn`t executed and step over it and I don`t know why? can you tell me why?

Thank you v.much...

Comment: Ok man I think this code will make it..
But when I add a new code to my function, it doesn`t executed at runtime.. I don`t know what to do? can you help me with this?

Answer (score 52):

I use: `something.TrimEnd('\0')`

Answer (score 14):

This was the first result in Bing, and it didn't have my preferred method, which is

```
string str = "MyString\0\0\0\0".Trim('\0');
```

Answer (score 9):

you just need to [Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.replace.aspx) it

```
msg.body="TestStrg.\r\nTest\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\r\n".Replace("\0", string.Empty);
```

Comment: here net connection is too slow :( to post soon

Comment: @Noldorin, that is incredibly rude for a difference of 3 minutes.

Comment: @Anthony: Not really. a) It's 4 minutes, b) It's bad etiquette to post an identical answer once several have already been posted, just to milk rep points. If I answer substantially late when a question has already been answered, I delete my response appropiately.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
msg.Body = msg.Body.Replace("\0", "");
```

Comment: It seems it should work. But I have now another problem & I need your help.
When I add a new line of cod to any class in my c# project. This line of code is not executed at run time and the debugger step over it. 
1) How to make the new code to be executed? 
2) Is there a property in Visual studio 2005?
3) Or is it something related to the c# project?

Thanks in advance for any try to help..

Comment: Thats sounds like the project is not being built, and so any new changes made are ignored. Check your project is set to build in the Configuration Manager

Answer (score 5):

It may have a faster result if you use LINQ

```
str.TakeWhile(c => c != '\0');
```

Linq has a better and faster performance.

Answer (score 4):

```
msg.body = sBody.Replace("\0", "");
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var str = "TestStrg.\r\nTest\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\r\n".Replace("\0", "");
```

`String.Replace()` will replace all the `\0`'s with an empty string, thereby removing them.

Comment: I'm not a C# guy, but out of curiosity what is the `@` for?

Comment: Actually won't work with the @ symbol because that means it will ignore the escape character and interpret the string as "backslash-zero" rather than escaping it to the null character.

Comment: @ = Escape sequences should NOT be processed.

Comment: @Chris: `@` is for taking in consideration the slash as a symbol. The answer is wrong, `@` shouldn't be present here, because one `\0` simbol is replaced, not two `\ ` and `0`.

Comment: So `@"blah\t"` is like Python's `r"blah\t"`?

Answer (score 2):

Keep it stupidly simple =*

```
return stringValue.Substring(0, stringValue.IndexOf('\0'));
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I had some garbage after the first \0 and that remained with the Replace methods from above.

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late here but, while String.Replace works most of the time I have found that I like the regex version of this much better and is more reliable in most cases

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...

 msg.body=Regex.Replace("TestStrg.\r\nTest\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\r\n","\0");
```

Answer (score 1):

This line should work:

```
string result = Regex.Replace(input, "\0", String.Empty);
```